# View controller takes time to load

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have 2 view controllers.
View controller A and View Controller B.
When I click on a button on View controller A, it pushes me to View Controller B. But when I click on button on View Controller A, it takes time to load the View controller B and shows some lag on the page.

I am using 3 collection views on the View Controller B.

Comment: Your main thread is jammed up, probably in View Controller B. Could you post some code?

Comment: I have commented my all code in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear. It still shows the same lag. But when I delete the collection views from the storyboard, the problem get solved. But I need those collection views.

Comment: Something is going on with your view controller initialization/loading. Only way to help is with some code examples.

Comment: Show your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: Are you doing any download tasks or any other background tasks before showing controller B?

Comment: Can you try select Clip Subviews on storyboard collection view. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Add your code here.

Answer (score 0):

use this when you call B view controller on button click
here is official document from apple
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Background work will here
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //UI Update will here
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why would a UI action (tapping s button) be on a background thread?

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Background work will here
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       //UI Update will here
        });
    });

Comment: Yes, I understand that the OP could have dispatched onto a background thread, but they haven't mentioned  this, so your answer is based in a guess.  Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to add a comment seeking additional information